# Why does ordering of class members of the user defined type matter in C++?

Tags: c++, class, member

Case 1:

```
class A
{
    B b; //error: identifier B is undefined

    struct B
    {
        
    };
};
```

Case 2: Using forward declaration.

```
class A
{
    struct B; 

    B b; //error: incomplete type is not allowed

    struct B
    {

    };
};
```

Case 3: Definition before usage

```
class A
{
    struct B
    {

    };

    B b; //does not throw error
};
```

This need for the struct to be defined before a variable of its type can be declared as a data member is what is confusing me. From what I recall, the ordering of members in a class did not matter. So I wanted to know why this happens, and how do I get around it if I want the definition of the struct to be in the private implementation but a data member of its type to be in the public interface.

EDIT: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907864/inner-member-visibility-in-class) post clarifies why types need definition before being used as function parameters or data members. But how does one work around this limitation?

Comment: The compiler knows what `int` is, without any further instructions, but the compiler doesn't know what `B` is, until you tell it to?

Comment: Hint: Unlike the first two examples, `cout << foobar` is not a *declaration*.

Comment: These three might be informative:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076026/c-forward-declaration-and-incomplete-type-is-not-allowed-error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44388500/field-has-incomplete-type-in-forward-declaration
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration

Comment: If you're trying to achieve best-practices, then your class's member-variables shouldn't be part of its public interface in the first place.  Make them private and provide the minimal amount of access to them that is necessary via public methods instead.  (and since they're private, they can go at the bottom of the class-definition where they will be out of the human reader's way as well, as less of a problem for the compiler regarding declaration-ordering)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the member func of nested class need a complete type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605300/why-doesnt-the-member-func-of-nested-class-need-a-complete-type) There's also what I would call a follow-up, except it was asked earlier: [Inner member visibility in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907864/inner-member-visibility-in-class).

Comment: Redid the question to be more consistent between cases, @JaMiT your second link helped, so I get why it doesn't work. So how does one work around this issue, given that I want the struct definition to be private but I want a variable of its type as a data member of the class to be public.

Comment: Surely you've heard of `private:` and `public:` sections of a class?  Don't be afraid to sprinkle them liberally around the class.

Comment: @MarkRansom does that not affect readability a bit? I was wondering if there was a way where I had one `public:` with all interface related content and one `private: ` with all the implementation related stuff.

Comment: It's not ideal, but you have to live within the constraints of the language.

Comment: @JoelShaji *"I want the struct definition to be private but I want a variable of its type as a data member of the class to be public"* -- I'd prefer a public accessor function and private data member, especially with an opaque type, but the "how" is to code what you wrote. `private:` struct definition followed by `public:` data member. With an accessor function, a `private` forward declaration before the `public` sections might be enough, but that depends on unstated details, which takes us a bit off-topic for the question as stated. (You didn't ask about readability.)

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 is easy to understand, you can't use an identifier that isn't known to the compiler yet.

Case 2 is a little more subtle.  There might be multiple reasons it doesn't work, but the simplest is that it needs to know the size of each member so it can calculate the offset of succeeding members and the total size of the class.  It can't do that unless the full definition is known.  You can use a forward declaration to have a *pointer* or *reference* to the struct, but not the struct itself.

Comment: Might be useful to also mention why you can't use a type that isn't parsed by the compiler yet, while you can in nearly every other language (i.e., C++ does only one pass - even in 2021).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas yes that would be an improvement, but at this point I don't remember why that is.  I've been working with C++ for so long that the way it works just seems like the natural order of things.  I imagine in C# for example a member doesn't contain the actual object, just a reference to it i.e. a pointer.

Comment: The point is that case 1 is not at all easy to understand since only C++ forbids this.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas you are free to leave your own answer.  If you understand this better than I do, I wish you would!

Comment: My knowledge of this is limited - I just know that these issues are the result of C++ compilers being limited by restrictions that made a lot of sense 36 years ago, but still persist today.